# How to read a text file and group lines together in node js synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, synchronous

I need to read a snort log file in node js synchronously, and parse them into JSON data so that I can store them inside a database. The problem is, snort log files are not just one liners. An alert in snort consists of 5 lines, and I would like to be able to store these 5 lines as one alert in the database.

I have tried using

```
     const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(LOG_FILE),
         });

         rl.on('line', (line) => {
         console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
         });
```

to read the file line by line and print them out, but it only prints them out line by line and I do not know how to group them together.

Here is an example of a snort log file:

```
[**] [1:1000001:1] ICMP test [**]
[Classification: Generic ICMP event] [Priority: 3] 
06/09-14:18:58.102020 192.168.137.91 -> 192.168.137.89
ICMP TTL:64 TOS:0x0 ID:20610 IpLen:20 DgmLen:84 DF
Type:8  Code:0  ID:1664   Seq:5  ECHO
```

So in my database, I will have something called alert, and these 5 lines will be alert with id: 1 and so on. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gather the lines in a variable, and then once you get a full entry do something. Like this:

```
let lines = [];
rl.on('line', (line) => {
  lines.push(line);
  if (lines.length>=5) {
    let log = lines.splice(0,5).join('\n');
    console.log(log);
  }
});
```

This is counting in groups of 5 lines. You could also use another criteria if you wanted, like a pattern match or something.

**NOTE:** If you use a pattern match on the first line, of an entry, you'll have to do something to check for the last one in the file (which won't have another one following it), like listen for the `end` event of the stream, and write the last `logPart` from there. (But since this example just waits for the 5th line, we don't have to do anything special to handle the last group.)

Comment: *Edit: my first version used a counter variable and string concatenation, but in retrospect an array seemed a better choice, and ended up being fewer lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Would this work asynchronously as well, or is it only for synchronous coding?

Comment: "asynchronous" in JavaScript is a little different than in other multi-threaded languages. Even though this is reading the file asynchronously, it's all in the same thread. So you don't ever have to worry about the events being out of order or anything, and events will never overlap (this would be a real concern in a multi-threaded language). So yes, this should be safe for asynchronous reading. If you are reading multiple files at once though, you'll want to make sure you get your closures right so that the different files are using a different `lines` array.